# How can i develop chat module in social networking portal using ASP.Net 4.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, chat, social-networking

I want to develop one social networking portal using the ASP.Net 4.0. How can i develop Chat System like Facebook using the ASP.Net?

Is there any idea or Sample for the Same?

I am developing a one Social Networking portal. Part of the Portal, I want to develop one to one chat module. So User Can chat with each other. In Facebook user can chat with his/her friends (one to one). So similar kind of functionality i want to develop using the ASP.Net 4.0.

Comment: ANOTHER social networking portal? Really?

Comment: Yes. its long term planning from my side...but not like for Facebook but more than that ans specific target group and activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look SignalR. And there is very good example:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr

Comment: Can we develop one to one chat using this library?

Comment: Yes of course. If you search SignalR on google, you will see a lot of chat example.